# How to convert SQL to linq for this query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I want to convert this query into linq, please help:

```
select 
  mr_ssample.objectid,
  mr_ssample.stcode 
from mr_ssample 
inner join mr_wsample  on mr_ssample.objectid = mr_wsample.objectid 
                      And mr_ssample.stcode in( select stcode 
                                                from mr_wsample)
```

i tried this in C#

```
var query = from ssamp in marineEntity.MR_SSAMPLE
                        join wsamp in marineEntity.MR_WSAMPLE on ssamp.OBJECTID equals wsamp.OBJECTID && ssamp.stcode.contains(wsamp.stcode)
                        select new
                        {};
```

However, I could not access `wsamp` in `contains`, or I dont know the alternative of this.

Comment: var query = from ssamp in marineEntity.MR_SSAMPLE
                        join wsamp in marineEntity.MR_WSAMPLE on ssamp.OBJECTID equals wsamp.OBJECTID && ssamp.stcode.contains(wsamp.stcode)  //but counld not access wsamp
                        select new
                        {};

Comment: No, edit it into your question...

Answer (score 2):

give this a try,

```
var _result =   from  a in mr_ssample
                join  b in mr_wsample on a.objectid equals b.objectid
                where (from c in mr_wsample select new  {c.stcode})
                       .Contains(new {a.stcode})
                select new {a.objectid, a.stcode}
```